# Finding the new coordinate of a pixel in an image rotated by center

Tags: c#

I have an image on which I choose a random point. The image is rotated by any degree the user wishes. The goal here is to find the new coordinate of the pixel. I have tried it this way with the function RotatePoint where the  original position of the pixel was (100, 370) and the image gets rotated by 270 degrees, but the new coordinate is not correct. How would I be able to get the correct new coordinate?

```
   static public void RotatePoint(float angle)
        {
            var a = angle * System.Math.PI / 180.0;
            float cosa = (float)Math.Cos(a), sina = (float)Math.Sin(a);
            float x = 100 * cosa - 370 * sina;
            float y = 100 * sina + 370 * cosa;
            Console.WriteLine(x);
            Console.WriteLine(y);
        }
   private static Bitmap RotateImage(Bitmap bmp, float angle)
        {
            Bitmap rotatedImage = new Bitmap(bmp.Width, bmp.Height);
            rotatedImage.SetResolution(bmp.HorizontalResolution, bmp.VerticalResolution);

            using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(rotatedImage))
            {
                // Set the rotation point to the center in the matrix
                g.TranslateTransform(bmp.Width / 2, bmp.Height / 2);
                // Rotate
                g.RotateTransform(angle);
                // Restore rotation point in the matrix
                g.TranslateTransform(-bmp.Width / 2, -bmp.Height / 2);
                // Draw the image on the bitmap
                g.DrawImage(bmp, new Point(0, 0));
            }

            return rotatedImage;
        }
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You perform 2 translation transformations on your image that you don't take into account into your coordinate calculations:

```cs
// Set the rotation point to the center in the matrix
g.TranslateTransform(bmp.Width / 2, bmp.Height / 2);
```

and

```cs
// Restore rotation point in the matrix
g.TranslateTransform(-bmp.Width / 2, -bmp.Height / 2);
```

Here is a fix, with both translations taken into account, where xRotationCenter and yRotationCenter should be your bitmap width and height:

```cs
public static void RotatePoint(float x = 100, float y = 377, float xRotationCenter, float yRotationCenter, float angleInDegree)
{
    var angleInRadiant = (angleInDegree / 180.0) * Math.PI;
    
    var cosa = (float)Math.Cos(angleInRadiant);
    var sina = (float)Math.Sin(angleInRadiant);

    // First translation
    float t1x = x - xRotationCenter;
    float t1y = y - yRotationCenter;

    // Rotation
    float rx = t1x * cosa - t1y * sina;
    float ry = t1x * sina + t1y * cosa;

    // seconde translation
    float x = rx + xRotationCenter;
    float y = ry + yRotationCenter;

    Console.WriteLine(x);
    Console.WriteLine(y);
}
```